# Created app listed as admin, but not developer

Tags: facebook, roles

Been a while since I did an app. I created a new app but I can't seem to find the advanced settings (sandbox, etc) for it.

When I viewed the "roles" page, it had me listed as an admin but not as a developer and I can't find anyway to add myself as a developer.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're an Admin then you're the top level controller of the application, and have developer privileges as well.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps, select your application on the left, and then in the top right of the information window there is an edit button (part of the settings header).

Once inside the settings click on "advanced" in the left menu, here you can enable sandbox mode.

Let me know if you need more help and I can post a screenshot guide.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox option you find when you go to edit settings of app, and then check the advanced tab.

If you are a admin of the app you have all the permissions you need, instead of that, admin role have more permissions than developer role.